# MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js and WebForms.js from CDN (FW 3.5)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, webforms, cdn, microsoft-cdn

I can't find ASP.NET 3.5 MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js and WebForms.js on Microsoft CDN, MicrosoftAjax.js is there, url is http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/3.5/MicrosoftAjax.js but I would like to get all ajax js from CDN.

Is this possible or these files are simply not od MS CDN, and if so are any other public CDN that I can use ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also I've found this:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNAjax35.ashx

Those are the links for the CDN for 3.5 or at least the two files they have.

Hope it helps